# How do i get a loop to read through subdirectorys and list files then go back to the directory i was working in and list the files therein python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, directory, subdirectory

I'm trying to find out how to list files in a subdirectory the return to the directory I was working in and continue finding files

#!home/usr/env python3
import os
files = []
pather = os.path
while :
for file in os.listdir():
if file == "for.py" or file.startswith("."):
continue
files.append(file)
while os.path.isdir(file) == "True":
os.chdir(file)
if os.pathisfile(file):
files.append(file)

print(files)

That's my code so far

If you could please help that would be amazing

Comment: Besure to format the code in your question properly. Indentation is important in python especially with nested statements and loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import os
files = [os.path.join(path, name).replace(os.getcwd(), "") for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()) for name in files]
```

Comment: @llya thats awsome